# wordpress check if multiple user id's are logged in

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for a way to check if certian user id's are logged in.I didnt really want to create multiple roles for these users, hence why i am looking for a solution.

this is what i have so far:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
 $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
 if (array(375,378,379,619,764,801,1 == $current_user->ID )) {
  echo 'Sorry you cant view this information.';
 } else {
   echo 'Hello Admin';
 }
}

?>
```

can someone let me know where i went wrong please?

Cheers Dan

Answer (score 1):

The PHP syntax is invalid as well as the way you check the array

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (!in_array($current_user->ID, array(375,378,379,619,764,801,1))) {
         echo 'Sorry you cant view this information.';
    } else {
         echo 'Hello Admin';
    }
}
```

I seriously don't think you should do this this way however, what if an update overwrites this? It looks to me you'll be exposing admin stuff. I recommend you put the 5 minutes in to creating those roles instead of writing a quick hack in a language you clearly don't know much about.

Comment: @danyo well I still nailed your question, I just didn't want to write code that could bite you in the ass if it got overwritten - especially in WP which is infamous for getting hacked anyway.

Answer (score 0):

check this and let me know then ---

```
 <?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
    // Not logged in.
} else {
    // Logged in.
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to save retval from is_user_logged_in() in a var like:

```
$exist = is_user_logged_in();
if($exist) //if 1/true user exist.
```